# Processing with Xbox Kinect: Cannot load SimpleOpenNI library

Tags: java, processing, kinect, openni, simple-openni

I'm trying to use the SimpleOpenNI wrapper for Processing on Windows 10 64-bit. I am getting the error below. The method I used was to add the library to the `libraries` folder in `C:/Users/user/Documents/Processing/libraries`. Is there something extra that needs to be done when manually installing libraries for processing on Windows 10?

```
Can't load SimpleOpenNI library (SimpleOpenNI64) : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: SimpleOpenNI64
Verify if you installed SimpleOpenNI correctly.
http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/wiki/Installation
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: SimpleOpenNI.SimpleOpenNIJNI.swig_module_init()V
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$2.run(PSurfaceJOGL.java:408)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
A library relies on native code that's not available.
Or only works properly when the sketch is run as a 32-bit application
```